# Lubuntu and internet connection

Tags: lubuntu, internet

I'm pretty new to Linux distributions and have a few problems:

1. During the setup I connected my laptop to my router and everything seemed fine. But now I am unable to browse to most sites: FaceBook, Google and YouTube work fine, so I know I have an internet connection. Other sites don't work: I keep getting an error that my laptop is unable to connect to the server.
2. I can't connect to any other WiFi networks then my own: I can find them, I can even fill in the password, but I can't click <kbd>Connect</kbd>.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: @Daniel: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/680871/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Second Problem: Are you sure you have the correct passwords for other wifi networks. Depending upon the wireless security the number of characters is different. e.g. if it is a WPA ,its 8-63 characters and unless you enter those many characters, the option to connect will be grayed out.

Problem One: Please post more info, regarding which site you are unable to connect. Also please copy paste the following commands and paste the output. To open the terminal , you can press Ctrl + Alt + t

Suppose you are not able to browse google.com, enter following commands

```
route 
ping -c 5 www.google.com
```

And post back the results.

Comment: So, Some more information: I just tried all websites that gave me trouble yesterday. The only websites that worked for me where facebook, google, wolframalpha and youtube. Every other website gave the error that firefox wasn't able to connect to the server. I haven't done anything in the meanwhile, but it seems that just now I was able to connect to every site I tried to visit.
I did what you asked and you can find a screenshot here http://postimg.org/image/4pccieeyx/ce732a14/

Comment: about the other problem, I am sure about the user and password. Still the connexion button stays greyed out like you said. Can you explain a bit more about that 8-63 characters, I am not sure what you mean by that. 
Kind regards
Jasper

Comment: Since websites are now working for you without you making any changes, I think it must be a dns issue.  Please verify this by typing on the terminal following command :  nmcli dev show | grep DNS

Comment: If your ISP's  DNS server is down/intermittent you would face this issue. What you can do is to set the dns server to an alternate address. This can be done via the network manager gui. On the top -pane , in network applet , click edit connections, Select you wireless connection, clikc edit , goto IPV4 settings, and then specify additional DNS server say 8.8.8.8 . refer https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using?hl=en   .

Comment: Ok, I did what you asked, here are the results: http://postimg.org/image/hrkgxspz5/ can you please explain what that command is you gave me so I can understand and reproduce it? 

Kind regards
Jasper

Comment: nmcli is command line tool for the network manager.  so the above command simply lists your network configuration and then we grep for DNS , since that was the config we were interested in. So next time when you face the issue of some sites not reachable, please modify your DNS server, and verify. If that works, please mark the thread solved.